# MySQL get the difference on joined table - stock transactions/inventory system

Tags: mysql, sql, inventory

I am not sure how to ask this, but I will try anyway. I have a DB structure that tracks stock inventory for each product, product lots and warehouse locations. This allows me to know exactly what products are on stock, at what price and on what location.

Basically I use two tables for tracking

- `stock_transactions` [id, product_id, lot_id, warehouse_location_id, type, quantity]

  1. `product_id` = Unique identifier for SKU item in the warehouse
  2. `lot_id` = Unique identifier for product lots that arrived into the warehouse.
  3. `warehouse_location_id` = Unique identifier of warehouse location
  4. `type` = type of transaction [IN = into location, OUT = OUT of location]
- `stock_transactions_serials` [stock_transaction_id, serial_id]`:

I am creating an entry in `stock_transactions` for every item we move from warehouse location to location. E.g. if I move 5 quantity of product A from location X to location y I will create two entries:

```
INSERT INTO stock_transactions 
(id, product_id, lot_id, warehouse_location_id, type, quantity) 
VALUES (1, 'A', 'Aq2er4', 'X', 'Out', -5)

INSERT INTO stock_transactions 
(id, product_id, lot_id, warehouse_location_id, type, quantity) 
VALUES (1, 'A', 'Aq2er4', 'Y', 'In', 5)
```

Some products we track via serial numbers. For example if above product would have serial numbers we would use barcode reader to scan which serail numbers of product A we have moved to another locations. The table `stock_transactions_serials` will track serial numbers for each stock transaction.

Now I have two problems that I need to solve:

#### 1. I need to get the list of products and quantities on stock (grouped by product_id, lot_id and location_id. I have achieved this by:

```
SELECT id, product_id, lot_id, warehouse_location_id, sum(ST.quantity) as qty
FROM stock_transactions ST 
GROUP BY product_id, lot_id, warehouse_location_id
HAVING qty > 0
```

I have created SQLFiddle with some data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb352/2.

#### 2. I need to get the right serial numbers for that stock. I don't know how to tackle this...

If I join the tables I don't get the right results, or my stock SUM's are wrong. Any ideas? I would need to somehow get the difference between In and Out transactions and get the right serials.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: I guess, you have to use sub queries.

Comment: @AT-2016 yeah I guess, trying to figure out how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `product_id` + `lot_id` + `warehouse_location_id` is the natural key for `stock_transactions`. You chose to add a surrogate `id`, so a record gets uniquely identified both by either its natural key or its ID. You chose to group by the natural key, but you could just as well have grouped by `id`. Is this assumption correct?

In that case you can simply aggregate the serial numbers per `stock_transactions.id` (i.e. concatenate them) and join this list:

```
SELECT
  ST.id, 
  ST.product_id, 
  ST.lot_id, 
  ST.warehouse_location_id, 
  sum(ST.quantity) as qty,
  STS.serials
FROM stock_transactions ST 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT stock_transaction_id, GROUP_CONCAT(serial_id) AS serials
  FROM stock_transactions_serials
  GROUP by stock_transaction_id
) STS ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id 
GROUP BY ST.product_id, ST.lot_id, ST.warehouse_location_id
HAVING qty > 0;
```

Comment: Hmm not familiar with the term natural key, but if I would group by ID then SUM would not be right?!

Comment: I see what you are trying to do... Very promising! I need to test and verify on some more complex dataset.

Comment: As to natural keys: A database may contain an items table. It's key would naturally be the item number (possibly the Global Trade Item Number GTIN), but you could add an ID. Then you'd suddenly have two attributes uniquely identifying a record; the GTIN and the ID. So the question is: do `product_id` + `lot_id` + `warehouse_location_id` uniquely identify a record in `stock_transactions`?

Comment: Great explanation thanks. Yes they do... Stock transaction means that you have moved one particular product (SKU), from a particular lot, to or from a particular location.

Comment: Good, then my assumption was correct and the query should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT st.product_id, st.lot_id, st.warehouse_location_id, 
       st.quantity as qty
       GROUP_CONCAT(sts.serial_id) as serials
FROM stock_transactions st JOIN
     stock_transactions_serial sts
     ON sts.stock_transaction_id = st.id
GROUP BY st.product_id, st.lot_id, st.warehouse_location_id, st.quantity
HAVING qty > 0;
```

Note:  This will produce a comma-delimited list of the serial numbers.

Comment: I have tried using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the same way but this does not work. Since it's one-to-many relation the SUM(quantity) will be wrong - multiplied by the number of child rows in the joined `stock_transactions_serials` table!

Comment: @PrimozRome . . . If I understand correctly, then it can just be added to the `GROUP BY`.